# Accessing Windows Authentication Web Page from Raspberry pi Browser

Tags: asp.net, linux, windows-authentication, chromium, raspberry-pi

We have a web page that we want to access from a raspberry pi, however the webpage in question is protected with windows authentication. Is there any way to pass this authentication across from the Raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Iceweasel is a port of Firefox which supports NTLM authentication on the Raspberry Pi.  As far as I know, that's currently the only actively updated browser that retains the authentication throughout a session.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome supports ntlm http auth scheme, you can read more about it [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/http-authentication).

If you're not using chrome (or chromium) then you need to check that your client has support for ntlm http auth scheme.