# TFS Web Access from the Raspberry Pi

Tags: tfs, raspberry-pi, tfs-web-access

We've finally got TFS 2013 up and running and would like to start exposing some reports on a web browser running on a Raspberry Pi.  Unfortunately, it won't let us authenticate using windows login.

Are there any tools that allow TFS information to be exposed as a web page without relying on Windows login?

Comment: It is possible to do some of this using the undocumented REST API's. I know of someone who has done this, and will publish his work once the REST API's are released.

Comment: Nice idea: this is to build a corridor display screen?

Comment: Any chance of a sneak preview @DaveShaw?  

That's right @GiulioVian, we want to stick the dashboard in a rotation on our corridor display.

Comment: I haven't seen it yet, as it's MS, I guess you will have to wait, or see if you can find them :)

Answer (score 0):

As for 'pure' TFS web access there are some options.

A nice answer is [Accessing Windows Authentication Web Page from Raspberry pi Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165212/accessing-windows-authentication-web-page-from-raspberry-pi-browser).

Another option is to tweak the IIS hosting TFS and enabling Basic Authentication (see [Team Foundation Server, Authentication, and Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A third option is to insert a reverse-proxy able to convert Basic Auth to Windows Auth, e.g. squid.

For Reporting Services (SSRS) is a different story; I may try [configure Basic Auth](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I cannot guaranteed everything works. In this case the best and secure option is to set up the reverse proxy and direct the traffic there.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an SSRS subscription that writes the report to a windows share then display those files in a browser. The file formats are a bit limited but I believe it supports html and tiff. Along with a simple bit of html/javascript to make the browser reload the page every X minutes and you could have an ok dashboard.

Of course this means you'll need to use the SSRS reports rather than the newer tfs charts, but you can create your own reports using the warehouse.

TFS online supports basic auth for alternate credentials but it appears you can't use this on prem (yet).  Also in the future it looks like you may be able to use the built in charting tools (they can be embedded into team dashboards now), so potentially with 2013 update 2 you'll be able to make a better dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's not officially supported, but I remember [Martin Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6438/martin-woodward) mentioned in one of the RadioTFS podcasts that [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40785) works on a Raspberry Pi - if I recall correctly, he actually changed TEE to work on it.

I have never tried it, but TEE should run anywhere you can get a JVM, and that includes the Pi. Then it's just a matter of using the object model within TEE to make a call to TFS.